# how to change imageView size depending on another item's size?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout which contains 2 items, one being a spinner and an ImageView, how do i set image view ratio based on Spinner height, in this case I set the height of Spinner to `wrap_content`, so the image can change it's aspect based on spinner's height.

```
           <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".28"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                <ImageView
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/drop" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share your  code over here

Comment: @sunita done, i edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout

                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".28"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                android:orientation="horizontal">



                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/drop" />
            <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".28"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/spinnerbg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

In Drawable ,you add spinnerbg.xml;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/InputBg" />
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:right="8dp">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp" android:gravity="center" android:bottom="10dp">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:toDegrees="45">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="#666666" />
                        <stroke android:color="#aaaaaa" android:width="1dp"/>
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
            <item android:width="30dp" android:height="10dp" android:bottom="21dp" android:gravity="center">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/InputBg"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```